# How to get incoming call notification when app is terminated from background

Tags: ios, pushkit

I am working on a VoIP app. I used `PushKit` in my app for getting notification. When my app is in background any incoming call notify the app and user can easily receive the call.

Now my problem is When I terminate the app from background there is no incoming call notification that is `PushKit` not working when the app is terminated from background. I came to know that `PushKit` not works when the app is terminated from background. is it right? If so then how can I do the work when app is terminated from background and incoming call will notify the app.

Answer (score 0):

While your app is in terminated mode then you have to make `Pushkit` payload like this.

```
$body['aps'] = array(
'content-available'=> 1,
'alert' => $message,
'sound' => 'default',
'badge' => 0,
);
```

On basis of payload you have to schedule interactive "Accept" and "Decline" button interactive local notification.

https://github.com/hasyapanchasara/PushKit_SilentPushNotification

Comment: I have implemented an incoming call VOIP when my app is terminated. But when I receive the incoming call on the terminated app case ```perform action: CXEndCallAction``` this delegate method is directly getting called. Suggest solution for this.